# cryptography module not found using Geany IDE

Tags: python, cryptography

I currently have this piece of code to create an encryption key

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()

with open('filekey.key','wb') as filekey:
    filekey.write(key)
```

But when I run the code in Geany I get the

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

Yet when I run it in PyCharm I don't get this error, in fact it runs fine. Most of my other code is in Geany and I'm not very familiar with PyCharm as a IDE so what should I do in order for it to work on Geany?

Comment: make sure you are using the same interpreter (venv presumably)

Comment: Many IDEs have special procedures to install third-party module so they can be found. Check the documentation.